# E2E test - Why does selenium shut down automatically after running the test?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, angular

I'am running an E2E test for an angular app. I did edit the **`protractor.conf.js`** in order to use SeleniumStandalone. It looks good, and I can run the test using: **`ng e2e`**.

**`protractor.conf.js`**:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
    // location of the Selenium JAR file and chromedriver, use these if you installed protractor locally
    seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar',
    chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.34',
    seleniumPort: '4444',
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        name: 'Unnamed Job',
        specs: ['./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts']
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

My issue is that selenium server get shut down automatically and immediately after the test is done. How to prevent this behavior? Is there an option to add in **`protractor.conf.js`** to fix this?

Here is the output in terminal after I run: **`ng e2e`**:

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[16:10:36] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/kvincent/PROJECT - DECEMBER/UserApp/19_12-t-04_16/consumer-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.34.zip
[16:10:36] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.34.zip
[16:10:36] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/kvincent/PROJECT - DECEMBER/UserApp/19_12-t-04_16/consumer-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.34
[16:10:36] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.34 up to date
[16:10:36] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:10:36] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[16:10:37] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.0.4:4444/wd/hub
Jasmine started

Executed 0 of 0 specs SUCCESS in 0.003 sec.
[16:10:38] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[16:10:38] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:10:38] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
aminkasbi@Amins-MacBook-Pro.local:~/PROJECT - DECEMBER/UserApp/19_12-t-04_16/consumer-app$
```

As you can see in the following line: **`[16:10:38] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.`** the selenium-standalone is being shut down and it looks like it's a normal behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutting Selenium is useful default for headless testing. I am not familiar with Protractor, but there should be a configuration parameter to keep browser open after run. And why you want browser to hang around after test, especially successful test?

Comment: Great hints and helpful answers! I'll go for the headless testing as I don't need a browser hanging around as Peter Masiar said.

Answer (score 4):

When you are [specifying `seleniumServerJar` and `seleniumPort`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup#standalone-selenium-server) you are instructing `protractor` to take care of controlling a selenium server. Protractor would then start it as a child process before executing your tests and then shut it down after.

If you want it to connect to running Selenium server, use `seleniumAddress` configuration option instead - Protractor would then try to connect to this running selenium server instead.

Comment: Agree. I had this option before: `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',` I started the selenium server from terminal: `webdriver-manager start` and was able to reach it. I did run the test: `ng e2e` and terminal says: `[09:14:19] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Jasmine started Executed 0 of 0 specs SUCCESS in 0.003 sec. [09:14:21] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running`. But I might be a kind of confused as I'am expecting to see the output also on: `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`, but it' still blank

Answer (score 1):

Since Protractor is a test framework build on top of WebdriverJS, Protractor handles certain aspects of the webdriver for you. For example, it automatically starts a browser (no need to call something like `driver = builder.build()`) and automatically closes a browser (no need to call `driver.quit()`). Protractor makes the decision to close a browser/end a session at the end of a test suite for you. Other answers have mentioned that the `conf.js` file allows you to choose where your Webdriver instance connects to or how the browser is started up.

However, there are some [helpful setup/teardown utilities](http://timothymartin.azurewebsites.net/protractor-before-and-afters/) such as `onComplete()` that allow execution of actions at various stages before and after a test suite.

Comment: Great! good one. The reference is helpful... helps me to understand what‘s really happens behind the scenes when unsing beforeEach, afterEach etc.